# Joomla component - adding new field to admin (back end) to filter query for front end

Tags: joomla, model, custom-fields

Hope someone can help me - I've been using the [Hello World Guide](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_%28MVC%29_Component_for_Joomla!2.5_-_Part_06#site.2Fviews.2Fhelloworld.2Ftmpl.2Fdefault.xml) to help me with adding a drop down field to the admin model that will filter the query in the front end model.

I've got the new drop down field all working in the admin side and pulling records from the database to select, but now I'm stuck on the last bit - "Display the chosen message". In the tutorial they extend "JModelItem" and return JTable but I need to create a query filtered from the value selected in that new drop down field created on the admin model.

In other words - how does the site model get the selected value from the drop down list I've created in the admin model?

I'm so close to making this work and really getting to grips with my understanding of MVC - if someone can point me in the right direction I'd be eternally grateful!

All the best

MB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i am right you want to access the admin component model to the site model, then you can try the following example for do this :

**Example :**

```
JModelLegacy::addIncludePath(JPATH_ROOT.'/components/com_banners/models', 'BannersModel');
$model = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Banners', 'BannersModel', array('ignore_request'=>true));
$banners = $model->getItems();
```

Comment: Thanks Tornado - I'll give it a whirl - where would I put that?  Also do you know where the admin component would store the selected value?  Many thanks!

Comment: Put this lines of code where you want to access it in your site component.